# How to send specific API data from one component to another called within React Component in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to react and I'm getting some problem sending data to other component files. I'm checking login user from backend Api in if statement I want if it's true then it should send user_Id to another component file. but can't have exported in another class component. what's the solution. please help thanks in advance.

```js
class Login extends Component<RouteComponentProps> {
  state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
    isChecked: false,
    user_Id: null,
  }
  async handleFormSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const postData = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }
    const response = await AuthService.doUserLogin(postData);
    if (response.code==0) {
      AuthService.handleLoginSuccess(response, this.state.isChecked);
      this.props.history.push('/home');
      return(this.setState({user_Id:response.result.user_id}));
    }
    else {
      alert(response.description)
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the component to whom you are passing the data is a child component, you should pass it as a prop.

For example, this component would be rendered inside a parent component, and will receive some props from it. (Note that the component shown below will be inside the render() part of its parent.)

```
<DeleteUserModal showDeleteUserModal={this.state.showDeleteUserModal} closeDeleteUserModal={this.closeDeleteUserModal} userDeleted={this.state.userDeleted} deleteUser={this.deleteUser} handleDismiss={this.handleDismiss} />
```

For example showDeleteUserModal={this.state.showDeleteUserModal} , means that in the child component you will be able to access that state using.

```
this.props.showDeleteUserModal
```

You can also pass functions that way and call them

If you have a complex structure of the app where passing components down to children is messy because there are a lot of components, you can also store states in a global enviornment, like redux